# Is it worth to rewrite an entire program?

Tags: java

I have a Java Project I have been working hard on for about 6 months (3 months hardcore) and it is around 8000 lines of code... However I have gotten much better then I was 6 months ago, and I have multiple classes that are full of messy, unorganized, and uncommented code.

Although my new code is much better, I often find myself lost when looking at some of my older code. Do you think it is worth the time to rewrite about `4000-5000` ish lines of code, that I think are not written well? I do not have much time to work, only about 3 hours a day max.

I don't know if I should accept that my old code was old, and just continue on, or if I should go back, completely rewrite most of my program and then have a easier path in the future. Or maybe there is a different solution? Any thoughts? Thanks! I really appreciate the help because currently I don't know if I should proceed knowing I may be just wasting time.

Comment: That depends on you.  I for one would see it as learning exercise.  I have a project that I've being working on for 4-6 years on and off which I'm thinking of starting it's 4th incarnation.  Basically stripping back all the code, throwing away those parts I don't want to use, cleaning up the API for other parts to make it more functional and introducing new code...but I'm crazy like that.  The worst position you can get into is having code you don't want to change because you've put so much time in it, despite the fact that it's garbage...

Comment: [Things you should never do, part 1](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

Having been in the same position (more than once sadly) I can say that it is well worth it - if you come back to one of your projects in 6 months time - you'll look at that old code and wonder what the heck you were trying to do. Also, you may want to send examples of your work to prospective employers at some point, and if they look at code which is sloppy - it doesnt look good. Worse yet, if they look at the code and see two wildly different styles (sloppy vs neat) they will think you plagiarised the code.

You will also (most likely) find that rewriting those 4k lines of code, results in far fewer lines of code. Or, that it results in code that is far more reusable. Try to think about DRY when you recode (dont repeat yourself) if you use something more than once, make it a function or a class.

Also, you will save LOTS of time in the future when you come to extend/change your work.

Answer (score 2):

Sure go for the rewrite.  You are still learning and probably learned a lot since you first started.  Now that you know more about programming and have a better idea of what the software requirements are you can probably make it much better.

Having said that, this is just a project for fun.  In the business world, you would have to consider the time it takes to do a rewrite in terms of money spent and time and money wasted not adding new features etc and compare that with the amount of money wasted trying to maintain the old system to keep it running.  Only if it's cheaper overall to do a rewrite will most businesses go for it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be very beneficial as the other posters have mentioned. You should take this opportunity to write **JUnit tests** for all your new code (if you're not already doing so), as this will help you write well-encapsulated and decoupled code. Two really good books for reference are Refactoring by Martin Fowler (http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html), and Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers (http://www.amazon.ca/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052).

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, but what are JUnit Tests?

Comment: Ah very good question - pick up TDD By Example by Kent Beck while you're at it (http://www.amazon.ca/Test-Driven-Development-By-Example/dp/0321146530)! That's the long answer - short answer: it's code you write that exercises your production code, and helps you think about class design.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question asked by many developers, and it leads to other more important questions that will aid you on your journey to become a better programmer.

Ask yourself:

- do i use javadocs in my code?
- do i often repeat code?
- do i use established patterns and stick with them for the entire project?

The reason i ask is that the answer to these questions will effect how readable your new code will be in the future even if you do rewrite your code.

A good excercise that will prove very useful in the real world is: can i optimize the existing code without rewriting it? this is a much sort after skill if ever you were to program professionally.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain quickly to me what javadocs are?

Comment: javadocs are pieces of meta data above classes, methods, fields etc that describe the functionality of your code. they are in the form: `/** ...some describing text... */` and you place them directly above the function methods or classes or whatever. then you can use your ide's functionality to read the 'documentation' of whatever you used it on (f2 in eclipse). its a fully fledged syntax that you can read about and use. i always use javadocs on everything i write and i never have a problem remembering what i've written.